# Share WPF Resources between 2 Non-Referenced WPF Projects

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, expression-blend, resourcedictionary

I have 2 Class Libraries that contain WPF Controls and resources in a Solution. I want to be able to share resources between them at Design-Time so I can actually see what I'm designing. At run-time everything is ok, as I am loading the dlls dynamically.

If I reference each project to each other I get a circular dependency issue

I am using blend & if I add a reference to the DesignTimeResources.xaml, a project reference is added which I don't want.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Create a common project, and have both projects reference it. Then you will not have a circular reference.

If you make the class static, then it is even easier to share data.

Comment: This wont work for me, I'll have to explain in more detail. I have a CommonSkinLibrary project which is shared by 10 other WPF Class Libraries in 10 Separate solutions. the WPF Application in each solution directly references the CommonSkinLibrary, therefore all controls in my WPF Application show correctly at designtime. When Editing the controls in the CommonSkinLibrary, they don't show correctly in DesignTime as the WPF Application is not referenced. Remember, there are multiple WPF Aplications reference this common project. The resources in each of the WPF Apps are all named the same

Answer (score 0):

The below link demonstrates step by step process to achieve your requirement. I hope this will help you.

[Set up the project for design-time debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514636%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)